# Compiled LAPACK slow

Tags: mingw, lapack

I compiled LAPACK 3.9.0 on my Windows 10 machine using mingw64 and CMAKE. I use it in my C++ program, and it runs, but it is 10 times slower compared with a Python implementation using numpy.linalg version that I have. What can be the reason? I cannot find any way to force O3's or anything of the kind somewhere. Below you can see my CMAKE settings.

[image]

I link liblapacke.dll dynamically to my exe.

Comment: Have you tried with the USE_OPTIMIZED_BLAS/USE_OPTIMIZED_LAPACK flags?

Comment: Yes, I did, and I got: [ 43%] Linking Fortran shared library ..\bin\liblapack.dll
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lFALSE
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: *** [SRC\CMakeFiles\lapack.dir\build.make:28027: bin/liblapack.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:245: SRC/CMakeFiles/lapack.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [makefile:155: all] Error 2

Answer (score 0):

I found a benchmark (http://markus-beuckelmann.de/blog/boosting-numpy-blas.html) that shows how the netlib blas package performs a factor 25 below OpenBLAS, for example. So it seems as though I just have to use an optimized BLAS package.

Comment: OpenBLAS (http://www.openblas.net/) builds with MinGW-w64, you should give it a go.